# Malloc on a struct containing a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, memory-management, malloc

Here is the situation :

I use a malloc to allocate memory for a struct.
The struct contains various items such as pointers, string variables and vectors.

The fact is, when we use malloc, no constructors are called. Using a code similar to the following one, I've experienced some situation where some variables worked while others didn't.

Note : The following code doesn't compile. It's purpose is only to illustrate the situation.

```
struct MyStruct 
{
    MyClass*    mFirstClass;
    bool        mBool;
    std::string mString;
    std::vector<MyClass> mVector;
};


int main()  
{  

    MyStruct* wMyStructure;  
    wMyStructure = (MyStruct*) malloc (sizeof(MyStruct));  

    MyClass wMyClassObject;

    wMyStructure->mFirstClass = new MyClass();  
    wMyStructure->mFirstClass->func();  
    wMyStructure->mBool = false;  
    wMyStructure->mString = "aString";  
    wMyStructure->mVector.push_back(wMyClassObject);

    return 0;
}
```

By using pointers instead of those variables (`std::string* mString`), followed by a call to the object constructor (`mString = new std::string;`) Exception are not thrown.

However, I've experienced a situation where the mString was used without problem without the constructor being called, but when it came to the vector, the application exit automatically.

This left me with many questions:

1. When will an object throw an exception if no constructor were used?
2. In the situation I experienced, only the vector caused problem. Could mString be left as it is or should I call it's constructor?
3. What would be the safest way, using malloc, to do the whole thing?

Comment: You *may* have an interesting question, but please please do rewrite this one, from scratch, and work on the presentation. Nothing in the question makes sense or is C++ (there's no `void main()` to start with). And please don't call your class "Class", for your respected readers' sake.

Comment: i see no call to malloc in your code. Lookup the 'placement new operator'.

Comment: @bmargulies: More aptly perhaps the "placement-new *expression*". The operator is fairly boring, and you don't ordinarily call the operator directly anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I was distracted when I wrote the question. I hope this time it will make more sense.

Comment: Well I can't really post the code I'm working on since it's not mine. As for the casting, I made a mistake, it should be MyStruct*. My main goal was not really to get the solution to the problem, but to understand the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code causes undefined behaviour, because your `wMyStructure` does not point to an object, so you may not use the accessor operator `->` on it.

An object only commences its life *after its constructor has completed*. Since you don't call any constructor, you do not have an object.

(If your struct were a POD, i.e. just consisting of primitive types and PODs, then this would be OK, because PODs have trivial constructors, which do nothing.)

The concrete problem you're facing is that the string and vector members of your struct didn't get to call their constructors, so those members don't exists, and hence the entire object doesn't.

If you want to decouple memory management from object construction, you can use placement syntax:

```
// get some memory
char arena[HUGE_VAL];
void * morespace = malloc(HUGE_VAL);

// construct some objects
MyClass   * px = new (arena + 2000) MyClass;  // default constructor
YourClass * py = new (morespace + 5000) YourClass(1, -.5, 'x');  // non-default constructor
```

(You have to destroy those objects manually, `px->~MyClass();` etc., when you're done with them.)

Comment: Ok, This I can understand. What I don't get is why the string variable was working well even though no constructor was called. Shouldn't it have caused an exception when I tried to assign a value to the variable ?

Comment: @Sim: Well, it's undefined behaviour, so anything could happen, including (most dangerously) exactly what you'd expect. Assignment overwrites, so it's possible that you might have got away with that; accessing (or even just calling `size()` may get you into trouble sooner. Anyway, just don't, it's not allowed and undefined, and there's nothing meaningful you can reason about.

Comment: @ Kerrek : Ok, this answer my question fairly well. I'll just call the constructors/destructors on every object contained in the struct.

Comment: @Sim: You can't call the constructors of member objects directly. You can only explicitly construct objects with `new` expressions. But **why** would you need to do this? This almost guaranteedly makes no sense. Post what your real situation is and we can surely find a proper solution.

Comment: @ Kerrek : That's what I meant by calling the constructor. As for my situation, I must use a function which will make the malloc on my structure. I believe some of the struct objects members must be allocated through this function, but I can't be sure since I don't have access to it's source. Along with those object, are some vectors and string variables. Exception were thrown when using the vector. I've been able to solve the problem by simply change the vector to a pointer to this vector and use the new expression. That's what left me wondering about the string case too.

Comment: @Sim: If your memory comes pre-allocated, then that sounds like a good use case for the placement-new. That way you don't need to turn any members into pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Using object without constructing it must be an undefined behaviour. Anything may happen at any moment. If you do this, you must not rely on any part of your code to run smoothly, because the language doesn't guarantee anything in this case.

Comment: Agreed. Even if it *looks* like it's working, bad things may happen down the line.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour to use a non-initialized object. Exception may be thrown at any time- or not at all.

Comment: Pedantically, there's no such thing as a "non-initialized object". An object begins its life when the constructor has completed. Otherwise there's no object.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 ) When will an object throw an exception if no constructor were used ?

If you don't call the constructor, there *is* no object. You have just allocated some space.

> 2 ) In the situation I experienced, only the vector caused problem. Could mString be left as it is or should I call it's constructor ?

This is all undefined behavior, just about *anything* could happen. There are no rules.

> 3 ) What would be the safest way, using malloc, to do the whole thing ?

The safest way would be *not* to use malloc, but allocate using `new` that will call constructors. It is as simple as this

```
MyStruct* wMyStructure = new MyStruct;
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers appear to explain what the compiler is doing. I'll try to explain.

When you call `malloc` the program reserve some memory space for the struct. That space is filled with memory garbage, (i.e. random numbers in place of the struct fields).

Now consider this code:

```
// (tested on g++ 5.1.0 on linux)
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S {
  int a;
};

int main() {
  S* s = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S));
  s->a = 10;

  *((int*)s) = 20;

  std::cout << s->a << std::endl; // 20 
}
```

So when accessing a member of a struct you are actually accessing a memory position, there *should* be no unexpected behavior when writing to it.

But in C++ you can overload operators. Now imagine what would happen if the overloaded assignment operator need the class to be initialized, like in the code below:

```
// (tested on g++ 5.1.0 on linux)
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class C {
  public:
  int answer;
  int n;
  C(int n) { this->n = n; this->answer = 42; }
  C& operator=(const C& rhs) {
    if(answer != 42) throw "ERROR";
    this->n = rhs.n; return *this;
  }
};

struct S {
  int a;
  C c;
};

int main() {
  S* s = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S));

  C c(10);
  C c2(20);

  c = c2; // OK

  std::cout << c.n << std::endl; // 20

  s->c = c; // Not OK
            // Throw "ERROR"

  std::cout << s->c.n << std::endl; // 20
}
```

When `s->c = c` is executed the assignment operator verifies if `s->c.answer` is `42`, if its not it will throw an error.

So you can only do as you did in your example if you know that the overloaded assignment operator of the class `std::vector` does not expect an initialized vector. I have never read the source code of this class, but I bet it expects.

So its not advisable to do this, but its not impossible to be done with safety if you really need. You just need to be sure you know the behavior of all assignment operators you are using.

In your example, if you really need an `std::vector` on the struct you can use a vector pointer:

```
class MyClass { ... };

struct S {
  std::vector<MyClass>* vec;
}

int main() {
  S s;
  MyClass c;
  s.vec = new std::vector<MyClass>();
  s.vec->push_back(c);
}
```